# SQL Server database doesn't save record after closing form C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have created a game but I want to save the users to a SQL Server database. But once I close the form, all the records are lost. But when I go back to a different form and don't close the application, I get all the records.

This is my connection string in `app.config`

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HighScores.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Code:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChickenBlaster.Properties.Settings.user_dataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

public SqlConnection conn;
string connectionString;

conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

conn.Open();

string query = ("INSERT INTO dbo.Highscore (id,naam) VALUES (@id, @sam)");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", txtUsername.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (if you haven't done that already)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `HighScores`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HighScores;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.